# Destructuring an ES6 array to an object property and skipping values

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I'm trying to destructure an array into an object property, and I want to skip the first value. I can skip the first value when destructuring to variable as such:

```
let [, b] = [1, 2]
```

*b=2*

But this does not work:

```
let dog = { cat: [] };
dog.cat[, b] = [1, 2]
```

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,*

Am I just doing this wrong, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

So this works, but it seems a bit clunky:

```
[, dog.cat['b']] = [1,2]
```

*dog.cat = [b: 2]*

If anyone knows a better syntax I'd love to hear it.